# What is this mysterious Windows 7 tray icon?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, icons

There is a mysterious tray icon that only appears on one monitor (dual monitors) in the tray in Windows 7:

[image]

I've highlighted the icon above. It resembles a lightbulb sort of shape with radio waves emitting from it next to a white 'X' in a red circle.

It gives no feedback when moused over or clicked. If I access the Control Panel to see the tray icons and notifications, it also gives me no clue as to what it is, and why it only inhabits one monitor.

Comment: Does it appear if you boot into Safe Mode?  If it does not you can use Autoruns to identify which startup registry entry is causing this icon to appear.  Is this a laptop with a 802.11 wireless adaptor?

Comment: I don't see anything in Safe Mode, but then again I might not understand how to see all the icons in Safe Mode.

This is a desktop PC. There is a Network Bridge and VPN Connection that are both disconnected.

I will try Autoruns.

Comment: I don't see anything on Autoruns that shows the same icon.

Comment: Did you try right clicking on it?

Comment: @odamn - It might not be obvious.  If the icon is not start, in Safe Mode, then there is some entry that handles it.  So the next step is to disable everything, reproduce the the icon not being there, in a normal boot configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound I am unsure what you mean

Comment: @DavidPostill right clicking gives no feedback

Comment: What part of my comment isn't clear

Comment: At a guess, it might have to do with an app to control lighting by WiFi or Bluetooth.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It is hard to tell if part of the symbol is a "light bulb" or a "key" :/

Answer (score 3):

It's from avast! Anti Virus. If you go to the "up arrow" and select customize the icons that appear on the taskbar, you can see that it is an avast! thing.